# Complex Mysql query to combine 3 tables Data?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in which I store followers, I have another table in which I store friendships
Now I have third table which stores stream data.

Its a social network, there are many reasons so I don't wish to have one table for follower & friendships (Means facebook subscriptions/friends)

Can someone presents a way how should I query streams table to pick activities of both friends & followings ?

Any help would be really appreciated, thank you

Here is simple Database Scheme, its not really like this but almost!

Okay here is database tables schema please,

Followers table.
Row_ID
User_ID
Following_User_ID

Friends Table
Row_ID
User_ID
Friend_ID

Stream Table
Row_ID
User_ID
Contents_ID
Time
Type

Comment: Could you post your table structure, and perhaps some example data. Even better if you can make it as a http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you looking for is probably best done as two distinct results sets... or a union of the two.

```
Select "friend" as src, author, post from friends f inner join streams s on s.author = f.id
union
Select "follower" as src, author, post from followers f inner join streams s on s.author = f.id
```

This is just some pseudo coding but it should give you an idea of how to proceed. Without knowing your database schema, this is the best I can offer.

Edit:

This might be what your looking for then

```
select user_id, contents_id, time from (
    select user_id, contents_id, time
    from followers f inner join stream s on s.user_id = f.user_id and f.user_id = "username"
union
    select user_id, contents_id, time
    from friends f inner join stream s on s.user_id = f.user_id and f.user_id = "username"
) order by time desc
```

This will return the data in time order, descending.

Comment: Okay here is database tables schema please, 

Followers table.
Row_ID
User_ID
Following_User_ID

Friends Table
Row_ID
User_ID
Friend_ID

Stream
Row_ID
User_ID
Contents_ID
Time
Type

Comment: Can you state how it will return me data ? In sequence ? I mean first friends posts & then following users posts ?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of ordering you want to do here, or grouping. Quite honestly if your going to group the results by friend or following first, then by other sorting.. then it's really two operations your doing, not one. I've updated my answer.

Comment: wow really cooperative people, let me try it, thanks for helping me out :)